Wagtailmenus does not seem to recognize the sub_menu tag in my install
First of all, all of these pages have the "Show in menu" item checked, and in my menu config, it has "Allow 3 levels of sub-navigation" selected. Apologies if I'm being short, but I lost this question the first time I tried to post it. The browser went into perpetual loading state.
There is a tutorial in the first few pages of the wagtailmenus plug-in. I'm following that tutorial, which cuts off half-way through and instead turns into a tag reference manual. The docs are terrible due to that, and it's a little bit of divination studies based on bad writing.
Based on the tutorial, however, I have in my config:
`    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'scripts',
    'settings',
    'triggers',
    'tasks',
    'schedules',
    .....
    'wagtailmenus',
    'wagtail_modeladmin',          # if Wagtail >=5.1; Don't repeat if it's there already
]
    .....

    TEMPLATES = [
    {
    ....
            "context_processors": [
    ....
                'wagtailmenus.context_processors.wagtailmenus',
            ],
        },
    },
    ]`

I have this menu structure:
    -my dashboards (There are no sub-menus here.)
    -settings
        -Triggers
        -Scripts
        -Tasks
        -Schedules

This is really just items created to get this displaying before I add additional items. I only want the sub-menus to display, but they won't do so.
My templates are setup according to the first set of reference tags and the templates there. I've had to guess at what they intended here to be the tutorial items and what isn't but it seems correct:
base.html:
    {% include 'custom_menu.html' %}

custom_menu.html:
    {% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailuserbar %}
    {% load webpack_loader %}
    {% load menu_tags %}

    <nav>
        <div>
            <header class='nav-header'>
                <span>Data Autopilot Navigation</span>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                {% main_menu max_levels=3 template="custom_menu/main_menu.html" sub_menu_templates="custom_menu/sub_menu.html, custom_menu/sub_level_2.html" %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

main_menu.html:
    {% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailuserbar %}
    {% load webpack_loader %}
    {% load menu_tags %}

    {% for item in menu_items %}
        <a href="{{ item.href }}" >
            <br><div>{{ item.text }}</div>
        </a>
        {% if item.has_children_in_menu %}
            <div>{% sub_menu item %}</div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

sub_menu.html:
    {% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailuserbar %}
    {% load webpack_loader %}
    {% load menu_tags %}

    <div>
    {% for item in menu_items %}
        <a href="{{ item.href }}">
            <tab>{{ item.text }}
        </a>
        {% if item.has_children_in_menu %}
            <div>{% sub_menu item %}</div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

sub_menu_2.html:
    {% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailuserbar %}
    {% load webpack_loader %}
    {% load menu_tags %}


    <div>
    {% for item in menu_items %}
        <a href="{{ item.href }}">
        {{ item.text }}
        </a>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

From debugging, it's clear this goes through the templates correctly into main_menu.html. When it comes across the tag:
        <div>{% sub_menu item %}</div>
It stops here and instead of loading sub_menu.html template, it completes the main_menu.html and exits. It doesn't even print the <div> in the beginning of the sub_menu.html template into the html output. So, it's failing on that sub_menu tag as defined:
                {% main_menu max_levels=3 template="custom_menu/main_menu.html" sub_menu_templates="custom_menu/sub_menu.html, custom_menu/sub_level_2.html" %}
The way it's supposed to work seems to be that the menu_items->item variable is passed to sub_menu template, where it becomes the menu_items variable when that section is called again. Thus, it's a recursive call that displays the sub-menus. This is in the docs..asort of...in the section:
**
The main_menu tag
The main_menu tag allows you to display the MainMenu defined for the current site in your Wagtail project....It also does a few sensible things, like never adding the ‘ancestor’ class for a homepage link, or outputting children for it.
Example usage
    {% load menu_tags %}

    {% main_menu max_levels=3 template="menus/custom_main_menu.html" sub_menu_template="menus/custom_sub_menu.html" %}

By default, you have to call the {% sub_menu %} tag within a menu template to render new branches of a multi-level menu. ...sub menus will be added directly to any menu item where item.has_children_in_menu is True, allowing you to render them directly...
For example:
templates/menus/main_menu.html**
    {% load menu_tags %}

    <ul>
    {% for item in menu_items %}
        <li class="{{ item.active_class }}">
            <a href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.text }}</a>
            {% if item.has_children_in_menu %}
                {% sub_menu item %}
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

However, this isn't working as expected. It's simple and doesn't deviate from the "tutorial" as far as I can tell, yet it doesn't work. I'm using Django 5.0 and wagtail 6.2.1 and wagtailmenus 4.0.1.
This is the output I get:
enter image description here
I've tried a hundred different permutations. I've also found two similar issues with sub_menu and tried the fixes there to no avail. This seems to be specific to my setup, although I can't see anything different in my setup from the tutorial. Help! Please!  :-)

I don't see an obvious issue with your templates. Things I would try for debugging this would include adding nonsense classes to your divs so you know what is printing what and/or temporarily swapping to use "add_sub_menus_inline" https://wagtailmenus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rendering_menus/template_tag_reference.html#add-sub-menus-inline

I could never get this working in these versions of the products. I worked around it by using includes and manual menus. Eventually, I dumped both Wagtail and django templating completely. Not because they weren't functional. This was just costing too much time and it didn't seem solvable. The bigger issue altogether seemed to be that CSS styling was too much of a hassle for that level of work. Two weeks later I switched to react/javascript on the front-end and turned django into a headless RestAPI using django-restframework. Django was not the issue, but I just didn't seem to be able to make any headway on getting themes and menus to behave the way I wanted using the combo I was using. Moving to Google @mui components made the entire thing do-able, simply because I could dump CSS altogether and code to what I wanted. Although I could've spent 6 months learning CSS and fixing the issues, that didn't seem to be a productive use of time. With Javascript I can still make my pages easily editable through config files and not have to worry about how they're displaying and clobbering everything around them.

The answer section should have a solution for the problem. A "forget this tool" answer can be useful as a comment but not as a possible solution.
